# AWS CLI - not working in a crontab

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I can run the command `aws --version` in a script and in the cli. But if I put this command into a crontab it does not work.

Crontab:

```
50 12 * * * aws --version > ~/yolo.swag
```

Error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: aws: not found
```

The aws command is in a bash script. And I get the same error message when I run the script in cron. How can I get the script to run the command fine ?

Comment: can you paste also content of your cron ? crontab -l ? Most probably you should put in your cron something like: SHELL=/bin/bash */1 * * * * aws --version

Comment: I have added my crontab. I think the path to the AWS command is as follows: `/usr/local/bin/aws` . How do I do that ? Remember that this is not bash, its a separate appliaction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the `aws` executable:

```
50 12 * * * /usr/local/bin/aws --version > ~/yolo.swag
```

Comment: This worked fine. I have updated my question though. As the aws command I am actually running needs to work within my bash script.

Comment: I have done so. How can I set the aws path globally ?

Comment: These tips also might help you to understand cron behavior: http://krisjordan.com/essays/timesaving-crontab-tips

Comment: The path is already absolute (/usr/local/bin/aws) if you to be able to call it just with 'aws' put it in your root PATH variable.

Comment: This worked fine........!

Answer (score 4):

Put this code before your command line to be executed into crontab -e

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Still valid after 7 years. Thanks @Roberto!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the login environment is not the same as the one in which cron runs. So basically the environment is not set i.e. all your `rc` files, alias, user-defined functions are not present to cron at runtime.

One solution is to source the profile/rc files that sets the required paths and aliases.

```
 * 5 * * * * $HOME/.profile; $HOME/.bashrc ; <your command>
```